# Backgroundcolor of NSTextfield

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

I use a `NSTextfield` as a label.
I try to change `backgroundColor` like this

```
let myLabel = NSTextField(labelWithString: "A Label")
myLabel.backgroundColor = NSColor.green
```

But it does not work. What´s going wrong?

Comment: Did you look at the `drawsBackground` property? It can be `false`.

Comment: Thanks @PeterTretyakov tretyakov" , that solves the problem. Is there a more generic way for the backgroundcolor or anNSView?

Comment: I don't know. You can create custom class, inherit it from `NSTextField` and put the logic there, but I don't think it will give a lot of advantages since you don't use `NSTextFields` a lot in your code. P.S. I've added the answer about `drawsBackground`.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set `drawsBackground` of your `NSTextField` to `true`. This `boolean` controls whether the receiver’s cell draws its background color behind its text.

```
let myLabel = NSTextField(labelWithString: "A Label")
myLabel.drawsBackground = true
myLabel.backgroundColor = NSColor.green
```

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextfield/1399416-drawsbackground):

> In order to prevent inconsistent rendering, background color rendering
>   is **disabled** for rounded-bezel text fields.